# Rsync : How to copy files from source to destination in loop sequentially ?(linux)

Tags: python, linux, copy, rsync

I have been using rsync and it is working fine... But we keep deleting files in the destination folder and rsync keeps syncing files from the source folder. What's the solution for this? I need to delete files from the destination and rsync should not keep syncs files again from source.

How to solve this problem for handle this programmatically using python?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow (SO). [SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiast programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: rsync itself cannot handle this from what i could find. You could either filter the files to sync beforehand (if deletions happen in intervals, only sync files newer than xxx) or define an exclude filter to filter on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the solution, please find python the code

```py
subprocess.call(['rsync', '-vax', '--exclude-from=./list.txt','/home/centos/python/source/', 'techguy@x.x.x.x:/home/techguy/dest/'])

textfile = open("/home/centos/python/list.txt", "a")

files = [f for f in os.listdir('./source/') if os.path.isfile('./source/' + f)] 

for file in files:
    textfile.write(file + '\n')
textfile.close()
```